# Why my answer Is deleted?

Tags: discussion, support

On 2nd march I have given one answer

[SQl is not working?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162572/sql-is-not-working/162585#162585)

and that answer is accepted and has 3 upvotes.

My question is that if that answer solved OP problem and accepted then Why My answer is deleted By moderator

Comment: Genuine question. Marius will definitely give you an answer :)

Comment: @RajeevKTomy thank you for your support, yes  I also expect answer From him

Comment: Your answers was flagged as being identical to [the one posted 20 minutes earlier](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/162580/146).

Comment: @Marius There is a difference between this two answers, as the first person has not mentioned default values in schema and I have added that  default values for db columns

Comment: OK. My bad. I reverted it. but next time, when your answer adds something to an existing one you can mention it in one line.

Comment: @Marius , Thank you ,I will take care next time

Comment: if there is small change between your answer and existing answer you must be edit existing answer

Comment: @vaibhavahalpara I would reject such an edit as "attempt to reply". It would be better to comment on such an answer to notify the person who posted the answer of a possible mistake/improvement/addition